# Is there an object that represents the current namespace in Python?

Tags: python, namespaces

Is there an object in Python such that `dir(object)` gives the same result as `dir()`?

If not, is there a way to create such an object?

Comment: Why do you want another way of getting the same result?

Comment: You can create virtual namespace.
Follow this link: https://www.codementor.io/@arpitbhayani/overload-functions-in-python-13e32ahzqt?utm_content=posts&utm_source=sendgrid&utm_medium=email&utm_term=post-13e32ahzqt&utm_campaign=newsletter20200212

Comment: @HeapOverflow, because `inspect.getmembers` has no such default behaviour.